# Assertion failed on pixel comparison with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compare individual pixels of an image with a specific value, but I  have an assertion failed exception at the 'if' statement (removing the 'if' all works).

The piece of code is:

```
Sobel(gray, grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
convertScaleAbs(grad_x, abs_grad_x);
addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 1, 0, 1, 0, grad);

Mat imfiltered = Mat::zeros(grad.size(), grad.type());
//Find and extract shape 
for (i = 20; i < (grad.cols-20); i++) {
    for (j = 20; j < (grad.rows-20); j++) {
        if (grad.at<char>(i, j) >= 40) {
            imfiltered.at<char>(i, j) = grad.at<char>(i, j);
        }
        else {
            imfiltered.at<char>(i, j) = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is at `if (grad.at<char>(i, j) >= 40)` statement.

And the error:

```
Assertion failed ((unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]) in cv::Mat::at
```

Whats wrong with this statement? How could I get this comparison properly done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the call to `addWeighted` seems wrong... Also you can use the `threshold` function instead of explicitly looping... Also probably you should access `grad` with `.at<short>`. Well.. a [mcve] could help

Comment: the call addWeighted  works fine...I know  but I'd like to try individual pixel checking

Comment: you inverted rows and columns.. `for (i = 20; i < (grad.rows-20); i++) {
    for (j = 20; j < (grad.cols-20); j++) {`

Comment: Many thanks that was it, now works.

Answer (score 1):

You inverted rows and columns.
Since it's faster to iterate first on rows and then on columns, you need to change you for loops to:

```
for (int i = 20; i < (grad.rows-20); i++) {
    for (int j = 20; j < (grad.cols-20); j++) {
       ...
```

---

Also:

- `grad` is probably a `CV_16SC1`, so you need to use `grad.at<short>(...)`
- you can use `cv::threshold` instead of your loops
- the call to `addWeighted` is probably useless. The 3rd parameter should be another image.